What are the electrical requirements for fitting (low-power) immersion heaters in the UK?
I've got solar panels, which can generate 7kW peak (in practice, measured on the output of the inverter) but I'm capped at 5kW export to the grid*.  So if I'm not using (much) power in the late morning, there's 2kW of sunlight going to waste.  I have a 5kWh battery but in summer that fills up pretty quickly.†
But I also have a hot water cylinder (heated by a gas boiler), with a vacant position for an immersion heater. So I'd like to put in a 1-2kW immersion heater.‡ I don't use much hot water in the summer  (already preferring to use my electric shower off the battery).
Running a dedicated circuit would be prohibitively expensive and/or require a fair bit of decorating.  Connecting to the upstairs ring main would be easier, though still not trivial; I could do a fair bit of the work myself even if I needed an electrician to make the final connections.  The only circuits coming into the airing cupboard near the HW cylinder are the upstairs lights (also serving the burglar alarm) and the central heating.  Both are fused at 5A.  The lighting circuit is obviously out of the question, and I'm assuming that even for 1kW (4.3A) the boiler circuit is too.
The inverter and battery are in the loft. Running cables from there to the airing cupboard would be really easy if it's allowed.  I'd even consider adding a socket or two if I could.
So what is actually required for connecting an immersion heater to the mains, specifically a low-power one.

* This is on G99 paperwork, where the electricity distributor decides how much I can export.  Had I known in advance that I'd be capped at 5kW I would have got all this sorted out by the installers
†  I have, to some extent, optimised my charging by telling the system not to charge the battery in the early/mid morning but to export that power instead.  Otherwise the battery is full before I hit peak generation.  The battery can charge at up to 2.5kW when it's not too full, tapering above about 80%. 
‡ Which would be connected via a smart switch that I can automate based on data from my inverter, probably in addition to a conventional switch as a cut-off

Switching a relay with a computer controlled switch driven by the data. But needs to meet the IEE regs as if you use the ring main supply. Even if you don't and run the immersion as DC then you still have to meet the regs and DC can confuse many...

@SolarMike exactly.  Maybe I should de-emphasise the automation, because I'm (much) more concerned about the regs.  By DC are you referring to digital control?  Because I thought I said I'd be running it off my inverter, hence AC.  I'm not messing with the DC from the panels. I'll edit for clarity

Bu that gave me a thought: the inverter is in the loft, and easy cable run away from the airing cupboard - but I doubt I could take my immersion heater wiring off its circuit.

By DC I meant Direct Current. The wiring to the inverter is rated for 7kW or more so should run the immersion without issue.

OK, I hadn't considered the DC side, so couldn't figure out how to interpret your comment. The panels are in 2 strings, one sitting at 280V (at the moment) and one at 220V but even attaching a load directly to the one that's within spec would confuse the MPPT, and is way beyond my understanding.  Although the inverter wiring must be specced for 32A, and the possibility of charging the battery off the grid means there's no rule against drawing power on that circuit, I didn't reckon it would be within the rules.  If it would, that's probably my answer (also it's new since I surveyed my wiring)

In parallel with working out how hard this is, I'm also trying to get hold of enough data to assess how worthwhile it could be - they don't make it as easy as they might to get hold of raw data for me to calculate

Why not check out "dump load controllers" which will switch when batteries are charged?

@SolarMike that's what I would have got from the installers.  Another term is "diverter" and the one that integrates nicely with my system is £245 - quite realistic.  It also has 3 outputs so would cover some of my other load automation ideas

If it is realistic, then fine especially as it is designed to match correctly.

Be sure to check plumbing and heating requirements, as well. A heater requires thermostatic regulation and overheat fuse to prevent water overheating, excessive expansion, and other safety issues. This shouldn't be difficult, though, since those devices are regularly used for electric water heaters.

@DrMoishePippik all have a safety cutout built in.  Most have a thermostat as well, though (if it's variable) I might set that to maximum and add a temperature sensor for control, and for my information (to allow me to answer "do I need to run the gas boiler?").  The diverter product supports temperature sensors
